# What does the dashed line mean under the BookTitle attribute of the BOOK entity?

Tags: mysql, sql, erd

Why is there a dashed line under the BookTitle attribute of the BOOK entity and what does it represent? How do I represent this in a schema on MySQL Workbench?

[image: Here is the ERD I am referencing]

Comment: Where did this diagram come from?

Comment: This is a practice diagram I got from my professor to work on understanding SQL.

Comment: So can you not ask your prof what it means?

Comment: I would if it weren't an online course and the Stack Overflow community responds much faster.

Comment: It's possible that this community won't have an answer for you. I'm wondering if this was merely an item that was selected when the image was created, but I'm no expert on ERD.

Comment: @ElliottLambert Nope. Not a forum. It is meant to be a Q/A collection. Mistaking this  for a forum is the reason for most mistakes which lead to downvotes, unkind comments, lack of answers, closed questions. Taking the [tour], reading [ask] might help avoiding this kind of misunderstanding.

Comment: Okay, "Q/A" collection, I ask a question, often providing more than enough information, and still get downvotes on a legitimate inquiry.

Answer (score 4):

The dotted line means that it is **PARTIALLY** unique. ie: if the database if for apartment buildings, the apartment numbers would be partially unique because they are only unique in said apartment but reused in different buildings.

Answer (score 2):

The ER diagram you included seems to be using a variant of Chen's notation.  In that notation form, the double outline indicates a dependent element (i.e. You can't have a book without an author writing it).  The dashed underline represents a Weak Key Element.  There are a number of resources for what the different elements mean.